# How should I pass desired query when ajax call in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel

Here is my script code:

```
 $(document).ready(function()
    {
      $( ".iCheck-helper" ).on( "click", function(){

            var sel = $('.i-check:checked').map(function(_, el) {
                    return $(el).val();
                }).get();
              // alert(sel);

              var value = this.value;
              var city_name =<?php echo json_encode($city_name) ?>;
              var start =<?php echo json_encode($start)?>;
              var end =<?php echo json_encode($end)?>;
              var room_count =<?php echo json_encode($room_count)?>;
              var member_count =<?php echo json_encode($member_count)?>;
              var selt_guest =<?php echo json_encode($selt_guest)?>;
              var selt_room =<?php echo json_encode($selt_room)?>;
              // alert(city_name);
              $.ajax({
                // alert();
                type: "POST",
                url: "hotelresults",
                data: {
                    key : sel,
                    search_city:city_name,
                    start:start,
                    end:end,
                    selt_guest:selt_guest,
                    selt_room:selt_room,
                    room_nf:room_count,
                    guest_nf:member_count,
                    ajx:'kik'

                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('.hotel_list').html(data);
                }
            });

      });
    });
```

Ajax call in controller:

```
 if(isset($_POST['ajx'])){

                $key1=$_POST['key'];
                // echo $key[0];exit;
                $this->data['key']=$key1;

                return view('hotel.list', $this->data);
$sqlCond = 'WHERE 1 '.$this->getkeycondition($_POST['key']);
            }
```

Here,I would like to pass the query given above only when my ajax function calls..How to pass this condition query only when my Ajax calls.
Please somebody help me..

Answer (score 0):

Inject the request class as the first parameter of your method and you can use it's methods to check if the request is made via AJAX.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()){
        return "AJAX";
    }
    return "HTTP";
}
```

Don't forget to add an alias to the top of your controller.

`use Illuminate\Http\Request;`